# How to ignore spacing around operators (ex: n + 1 -> n+1) in vscode formatting?

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting

In vs code formatting, I wanna have spaces around operators when I want it.
When I did "Format Document" in vscode, spacing around operators is Default. But I think that has too many spaces to read a code.

I want my code to format like

before :
e = 2 * a + 3 * b + c * d;

after :
e = 2*a + 3*b + c*d;

I read the clang format document and vscode's formatting settings but I cannot find the solution..